# Analytical and Geometrical Properties of Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, analysis, soft-question

I often see expressions like "....analytical and geometrical properties of spaces..." in textbooks. Can you give some examples of what these properties are in normed space? For example, is it an analytic property that space is complete, or is it a geometric property that a closed unit ball is convex? On what basis is this distinction made?